# display user according to there last chats in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have created a one to one personal chat application for my college project. As users chat with each other there chats are been stored in `Firebase` as in the following manner

```
   + Chats 
      +currentuser
        +Reciverid
          +postPushid
            +informations
```

[image: image of the firebase data]

I want to display the users to whom the current user had a conversation according to there the last message means as the new message is been inserted under the current user chat node that users id should show on the top as according to there time of insertion.

Help me out to arrange according to user ids according to there last message time in `Firebase`.

Comment: If you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far in code and what exactly doesn't work the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I already implemented the same logic. I did other model of chats. I have separate table with users. Separate table with chats where each user see only users he got chat with. And I have separate table for messages where id is the chat. So in this case it is very to manage and it is flexible. You can add/remove fields from each model separately. Want time stamp in messages no problem. Want timestamp in chats no problem. All tables maximum got two levels instead of five you got. So i would recommend think about restructure of db.

Answer (score 0):

Just add one more attribute as timestamp and generate it by using the command

```
long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

save that to firebase when uploading the chat message with a negative sign like

```
timestamp = -timestamp;
```

Now in Query variable just add the this

```
query.orderByChild("timestamp");
```

this will select the value which is least but the value in positive becomes least in negative and that's how it gets **resolved**.